# What to use for itemize/enumerate/description type question

Tags: lists, environments, best-practices

I have a lemma in which I want to say something like this:

> Let f be a function which satisfies either
>
> (A) f=0 and f is continuous, or
>
> (B) f=1 and f is well-defined.
>
> Then f is good.

My question is, what environment should I use for the two options (A) and (B)? Should I use `enumerate`, `itemize` or `description`, or something else? I may say later on "If f satisfies the case (A), then ..."

Comment: If one knows what the counter name is being used by \item (which depends on what packages are loaded) one could do something like \renewcommand\theenumi{(\Alph{enumi})}

Answer (score 5):

The natural structure to use here is an enumerated list. Using the [`enumitem`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/enumitem) package you can easily change the counter representation to have the desired formatting:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{amsthm}

\newtheorem{lem}{Lemma}

\begin{document}

\begin{lem}
Let $f$ be a function which satisfies either
\begin{enumerate}[label=\textup{(\Alph*)}]
  \item\label{ite:casea} $f=0$ and $f$ is continuous, or
  \item\label{ite:caseb} $f=1$ and $f$ is well-defined.
\end{enumerate}
Then $f$ is good.
\end{lem}

\begin{proof}
If $f$ satisfies the conditions of Case~\ref{ite:casea} then\ldots\ On the other hand, if $f$ satisfies the conditions of Case~\ref{ite:caseb} then\ldots
\end{proof}

\end{document}
```

[image]